# How do i create dynamic urls for pagination in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

I am trying to create the Dynamic URL in Codeigniter. My Following URL is working fine

> http://127.0.0.1/Mytredin_codesup/tags/user-interface

Where `tags` in URL is a static value and `user-interface` is a dynamic value. But when I click on Next button of pagination following URL made

> http://127.0.0.1/Mytredin_codesup/tags/user-interface/1

and gives `404 pages not found error`

What I tried for this

```
$route['tags/(:num)'] = 'tags/index/$1';
$route['tags/(:any)'] = 'tags/view/$1';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work,

```
$route['tags/(:any)'] = 'tags/index/$1';
$route['tags/(:any)'] = 'tags/view/$1';
$route['tags/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'tags/index/$1/$2';
$route['tags/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'tags/view/$1/$2';
```

and method arguments should have

```
public function index($type, $id='')
public function view($type, $id='')
```

Make sure of this otherwise, it will throw an error.

You were adding `$1` in key of routes which `CI` won't accept.

Comment: Have you followed my all steps?

Comment: @UpasanaChauhan Hurry, I am gonna leave office soon.

Comment: $route['tags/(:num)'] = 'tags/index/$1';
$route['tags/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'tags/view/$1';
$route['tags/(:any)'] = 'tags/view/$1';

THis worked for me but now pagination loading the same content on every page....

Comment: get `$id` and as page number and pass it in query

Comment: Can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55664349/getting-the-same-data-on-pagination-in-codeigniter